# Error with GAMM when specifying correlation structure

Tags: r, time-series, gam, mgcv, autocorrelation

I have a timeseries dataset that I'm trying to model with a GAM.  Unfortunately, there is a lot autocorrelation in the data, so I'm trying to include an correlation term in the model.

Presently, I can run my model without any issues, when it is specified as below without issues, but this does not address the autocorrelation issue:

```
m <- gam(MASS ~ 
           s(YEAR.s, SITE, bs = "fs", by = AGE, k = 5) +
           s(AGE, bs = "re") +
           s(YEAR.f, bs = "re") +
           SITE:DOY.s,
          data = df, control = gam.control(nthreads = 4))
```

So I've tried to run it again with gamm and a correlation structure, but I keep getting an error message that I'm unclear how to address:

```
m <- gamm(MASS ~ 
           s(YEAR.s, SITE, bs = "fs", by = AGE, k = 5) +
           s(AGE, bs = "re") +
           s(YEAR.f, bs = "re") +
           SITE:DOY.s,
          data = df, control = gam.control(nthreads = 4), correlation = corAR1(form = ~ YEAR.s | AGE + SITE))
Error: 'sumLenSq := sum(table(groups)^2)' = 6.20123e+09 is too large.
Too large or no groups in your correlation structure?
```

**I'm anticipating that the values collected at the same site for individuals of the same age in subsequent years will be correlated. But perhaps I have not entered this correctly?**

Here is the structure of my dataset:

```
str(salmon)
'data.frame':   172048 obs. of  11 variables:
 $ SITE         : Factor w/ 19 levels "1","2",...: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ AGE          : Factor w/ 2 levels "1","2": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ MASS         : num  515 525 540 500 510 517 520 523 525 526 ...
 $ YEAR.s       : num [1:172048, 1] -1.46 -1.46 -1.46 -1.46 -1.46 ...
  ..- attr(*, "scaled:center")= num 1998
  ..- attr(*, "scaled:scale")= num 12.5
 $ DOY.s        : num [1:172048, 1] -1.25 -1.25 -1.25 -1.22 -1.22 ...
  ..- attr(*, "scaled:center")= num 211
  ..- attr(*, "scaled:scale")= num 35.1
 $ YEAR.f       : Factor w/ 53 levels "1970","1971",..: 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 ...
```

YEAR.s is a continuous year variable that has been centred and scaled (mean = 0, sd = 1) before going in the model.
YEAR.f is a factor year variable for capturing inter-annual variability.
There are no missing (NA) values in any of the variables going into the model, and there is a minimum of at least 20 years of data for each combination of SITE and AGE, but not all SITES have all AGES (e.g., SITE A might have AGE 1 & 2, but SITE B may only have AGE 2).